# In asp.net-mvc, what is the correct way to handle double quotes in a string variable being put into an input value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, string, encoding, double-quotes

I have the following code in my view of an asp.net-mvc site:

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="riskIssues[0].Reason" value="<% = risk.Reason %>"  />
```

The issue is that if there is a double quote inside the risk.Reason variable lets say the reason is a string that is something like:

```
  We need them to "ask" us first
```

and then i try to read the value using jquery ($("#test").val(), i only get the text that is before the double quote (in the example above, i would get

```
  We need them to
```

What is the correct way to encode this so I can read the whole string including the double quotes and everything after

Comment: can you use html encoding?  `"` would become `&quot;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<%: risk.Reason %>` to encode your text.

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncoding` or `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` to html encode your data received in your view. As shown in the examples [here (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) & [here (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your string would end up looking like this:

```
 We need them to "ask" us first

 We need them to &quot;ask&quot; us first
```

Also have a look [here (dotnetperls)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eb2uamn/)

Comment: Yes added a fiddle to demonstrate.